# IdentityServer 3 vs Active Directory Federation Services

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, saml, adfs, identityserver3

Active Directory Federation Service and IdentityServer3 are both STSes that allows Single sign-on to software systems.

I read that IdentityServer3 can use smaller (than SAML 2.0 in AD FS) JWT tokens and can be highly customizable like using different user repository.

But if I have all users in Active Directory and I can accept this bigger tokens and provide resources using AD groups will I have any benefits using IdentityServer?

In my system architecture I want to have WebAPIs connected using ESB. I will have different types of apps like mobile, Angular, desktop. I would like to use solution that will be more reliable than flexible.

Comment: There is some good information in the following thread, specifically Brock's comments: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API normally implies OAuth. ADFS 3.0 has limited support for this. ADFS 4.0 has the full stack.

ADFS 4.0 wrt. web API is functionally the same as idsrv.

Also ADFS in some cases does support JWT.

Comment: Thanks for mention that is version 4.0 in Windows Server 2016. So I think IdSrv provides: more custimization, open code (so even more customization you can make) and hybrid flow support: http://openid.net/certification/.

Comment: Agreed - idsrv is much more flexible than ADFS when it comes to customization and protocol support. Many people also use idsrv in conjunction with ADFS - ADFS for authentication - idsrv for the better protocol support and custom bits. Also ADFS 4 is tied to a specific OS . idsrv is not.